# html element won't follow cursor on mousedown and mousemove

Tags: javascript, html

As long as i mousedown on paragraph i trigger 'mousemove' event which should make the element follow the cursor but it's jerky and only moves when i click it...

```js
let p = document.querySelector('p');
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
    p.style.left = `${e.clientX}px`;
    p.style.top = `${e.clientY}px`
  })
})
```

```css
p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the event object (`e`) supplied by the `mousemove` event handler:

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p');

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    p.style.left = `${e.clientX}px`;
    p.style.top = `${e.clientY}px`
  })
})
```

```css
p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>paragraph</p>
```